# Magento not loading helper on production

Tags: php, magento

I am running a Magento custom module (just for a single helper) which loads fine on local, but throws this error on production:

```
Warning: include(Mage/Webviews/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /media/ephemeral0/vep_mage-primaries-prod/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I checked in the backend advanced module output and the module is not listed there, which means Magento is not picking it up. On my dev machine it loads perfectly, as soon as I deploy the module is not being loaded, I cleared the cache (even with rm -rf *) and php -f shell/compiler.php -- state (which is disabled). Magento logs seems empty.

What could be the cause of this?
Is there any other hidden cache? How come magento is not logging anything if the module is not loaded?

Thank you for any help, I'm pretty desperate.

EDIT ADDED config.xml (redacted company name)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Redacted_Webviews>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Redacted_Webviews>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <webviews>
                <class>Redacted_Webviews_Helper</class>
            </webviews>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

Comment: show config.xml code..

Comment: Added config.xml code

Comment: Configuration of what? The local.xml or something else?

Comment: Redacted_Webviews.xml in your app/etc/module/ this file? module configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Working perfect

**app/etc/module/Redacted_Webviews.xml** configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Redacted_Webviews>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Redacted_Webviews>
  </modules>
</config>
```

you config file **app/code/local/Redacted/Webviews/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Redacted_Webviews>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Redacted_Webviews>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <webviews>
                <class>Redacted_Webviews_Helper</class>
            </webviews>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

your helper data   **app/code/local/Redacted/Webviews/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

class Redacted_Webviews_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{



}
```

Comment: I know it works perfectly, locally it works, is a problem of the live site.
Is there any other cache hidden in the database or other places?

Comment: it work in live site too. just disabled  the cache and install your module.